# How to compare output of wordnet.synsets?

Tags: nltk, python-3.5, wordnet

I want compare output from the wordnet.synset function in the NLTK library. In an example when I run:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synsets('dog')
```

I get output:

```
output:
        [Synset('dog.n.01'),
     Synset('frump.n.01'),
     Synset('dog.n.03'),
     Synset('cad.n.01'),
     Synset('frank.n.02'),
     Synset('pawl.n.01'),
     Synset('andiron.n.01'),
     Synset('chase.v.01')]
```

Now if I try:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
    wn.synsets('dogg')
```

I get output

```
output: 
[]
```

**How can I compare the outputs in the console to build logic around it?** Logic could be "if word not in output then mispelled"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's sound to do the "if word not in output then mispelled", because you're assuming that the universe of words are all wordnet. Possibly, you're looking for something like: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L66 ?

Comment: @alvas thank you so much for the link it is what I am looking for!

Comment: I don't get it. Your logic is already directly implementable, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate each word through nltk synsets and store misspelled words in separate list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490777/how-to-iterate-each-word-through-nltk-synsets-and-store-misspelled-words-in-sepa)