# How to iterate each word through nltk synsets and store misspelled words in separate list?

Tags: python, iteration, nltk, python-3.5, wordnet

I am trying to take a text file with messages and iterate each word through NLTK wordnet synset function. I want to do this because I want to create a list of mispelled words. For example if I do:

```
wn.synsets('dog')
```

I get output:

```
[Synset('dog.n.01'),
 Synset('frump.n.01'),
 Synset('dog.n.03'),
 Synset('cad.n.01'),
 Synset('frank.n.02'),
 Synset('pawl.n.01'),
 Synset('andiron.n.01'),
 Synset('chase.v.01')]
```

now if the word is mispelled like so:

```
wn.synsets('doeg')
```

I get output:

```
[]
```

If I am returned an empty list I want to save the misspelled word in another list like so and while continuing to iterate through rest of the file:

```
mispelled_words = ['doeg']
```

I am at a loss how to do this, here is my code below, I would need to do the iterating after variable "chat_message_tokenize". The name path is words I want to drop:

```
import nltk
import csv
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer


def text_function():
    #nltk.download('punkt')
    #nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

    # Read in chat messages and names files
    chat_path = 'filepath.csv'
    try:
        with open(chat_path) as infile:
            chat_messages = infile.read()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return

    name_path = 'filepath.txt'
    try:
        with open(names_path) as infile:
            names = infile.read()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return

    chat_messages = chat_messages.split('Chats:')[1].strip()
    names = names.split('Name:')[1].strip().lower()

    chat_messages_tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(chat_messages)
    names_tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(names)

    # adding part of speech(pos) tag and dropping proper nouns
    pos_drop = pos_tag(chat_messages_tokenized)
    chat_messages_tokenized = [SnowballStemmer('english').stem(word.lower()) for word, pos in pos_drop if pos != 'NNP' and word not in names_tokenized]

    for chat_messages_tokenized 

    if not wn.synset(chat_messages_tokenized):
        print('empty list')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text_function()    

#    for s in wn.synsets('dog'):
#          lemmas = s.lemmas()
#    for l in lemmas:
#          if l.name() == stemmer:
#              print (l.synset())


    csv_path ='OutputFilePath.csv'
    try:
        with open(csv_path, 'w') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for word in chat_messages_tokenized:
                writer.writerow([word])
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text_function()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just loop through the words, and check whether the returned list is empty, if so put in a list? It seems like you already know the logic of your function but you just don't know how to code it? But your explanation actually already describes the pseudocode on how to code it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare output of wordnet.synsets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455417/how-to-compare-output-of-wordnet-synsets)

Comment: Your other question is essentially similar to this one, but this one with more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the pseudocode in your explanation, you can just code it as you have explained, as follows:

```
misspelled_words = []                 # The list to store misspelled words
for word in chat_messages_tokenized:  # loop through each word
    if not wn.synset(word):           # if there is no synset for this word
        misspelled_words.append(word) # add it to misspelled word list

print(misspelled_words)
```